# How to efficiently extract a portion of JSON as a Vec without intermediate structs?

Tags: json, rust, serde, serde-json

I have JSON content where, deeply nested, there is an array of numbers I want to extract. I'd like to not create the intermediate structs, so I tried the following:

```rust
... get f
let json = serde_json::from_reader::<_, serde_json::Value>(f)?;
let xs: Vec<(f64, f64)> = serde_json::from_value(json["subtree"][0])?;
```

This complains with

```
11 | serde_json::from_value(json["subtree"][0])?;
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `serde_json::value::Value`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

If I `clone`, it works fine:

```rust
let xs: Vec<(f64, f64)> = serde_json::from_value(json["subtree"][0].clone())?;
```

But this seems unnecessary. I will not be using the rest of the structure. How do I achieve this without having to create the intermediate structs and without having to clone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, missed the totally obvious.

```rust
... get f
let mut json = serde_json::from_reader::<_, serde_json::Value>(f)?;
let xs: Vec<(f64, f64)> = serde_json::from_value(json["subtree"][0].take())?;
```

Comment: Heh, nice one. I completely missed _I won't be using rest of the structure_ in your question. Mark this as an answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @zrzka Please leave your answer online. It's useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use [`Value::pointer`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html#method.pointer). An example:

```rust
use serde_json::json;

fn main() {
    let value = json!({
        "deeply": {
            "nested": {
                "array": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            }
        }
    });

    let numbers: Vec<u64> = value
        .pointer("/deeply/nested/array")
        .unwrap()
        .as_array()
        .unwrap()
        .iter()
        .map(|x| x.as_u64().unwrap())
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", numbers);
}
```

**NOTE**: This example contains excessive use of `unwrap()` calls which
is dangerous and can lead to panics. It's there to make the whole
example simpler.

---

> Aren’t you still constructing multiple vectors in this case?

No. Let's expand this whole machinery.

```rust
use serde_json::{json, Value};
use std::iter::Map;
use std::slice::Iter;

fn main() {
    let value: Value = json!({
        "deeply": {
            "nested": {
                "array": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            }
        }
    });

    // Option<&Value> - Option & reference
    //
    //    pub enum Option<T> {
    //        None,
    //        Some(T),
    //    }
    //
    // T = &Value - reference
    let maybe_value_ref: Option<&Value> = value.pointer("/deeply/nested/array");

    // &Value - reference
    let value_ref: &Value = maybe_value_ref.unwrap();

    // Option<&Vec<Value>> - Option & reference
    //
    //    pub enum Option<T> {
    //        None,
    //        Some(T),
    //    }
    //
    // T = &Vec<Value> - reference to Vec
    let maybe_vec_ref: Option<&Vec<Value>> = value_ref.as_array();

    // &Vec<Value> - reference
    let vec_ref: &Vec<Value> = maybe_vec_ref.unwrap();

    // Iter<Value> allocation
    //
    //    pub struct Iter<'a, T: 'a> {
    //        ptr: *const T,
    //        end: *const T,
    //        _marker: marker::PhantomData<&'a T>,
    //    }
    //
    // .next() returns Option<&Value>
    let vec_ref_iter: Iter<Value> = vec_ref.iter();

    // Map<..., ...> allocation
    //
    //    pub struct Map<I, F> {
    //        iter: I,
    //        f: F,
    //    }
    //
    // .next() returns Option<u64>
    let vec_ref_iter_map: Map<Iter<Value>, fn(&Value) -> u64> =
        vec_ref_iter.map(|x: &Value| x.as_u64().unwrap());

    // Nothing happens till this point. I mean, only Iter, Map, ... structures
    // were allocated. But because they're lazy, we have to consume the last
    // Map (vec_ref_iter_map) to fire the whole machinery.
    //
    // What's going on (simplified)?
    //
    // * Vec implements FromIterator
    // * vec_ref_iter_map implements Iterator
    // * FromIterator consumes vec_ref_iter_map.next() till None (= end)
    // * vec_ref_iter_map.next() returns Option<u64>
    //   * it internally gets vec_ref_iter.next() value
    //   * if value is None then None is returned (= end)
    //   * if value is Some(x) then it applies .map() closure (x.as_u64().unwrap())
    //     and returns Some(closure result)
    //
    // The only allocated Vec here is the last one (numbers). No other Vectors
    // were allocated.
    let numbers: Vec<u64> = vec_ref_iter_map.collect();

    println!("{:?}", numbers);
}
```

Documentation:

- [`std::slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html)
- [`std::iter::Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html)
- [`std::iter::Iterator.next()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next)
- [`std::iter::Map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Map.html)
- [`std::iter::Map impl Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Map.html#impl-Iterator)
- [`std::iter::FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html)
- [`std::vec::Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html)
- [`std::vec::Vec impl FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-FromIterator%3CT%3E)

Comment: Aren’t you still constructing multiple vectors in this case?

Comment: @Listerone see updated answer (end of it). Every step result stored to a temporary variable, annotated with type and some comments. Should help to understand what's going on. If not, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned in your question that you don't actually need the rest of the JSON data, maybe the [Struson](https://crates.io/crates/struson) library and its [`seek_to`](https://docs.rs/struson/0.2.0/struson/reader/trait.JsonReader.html#tymethod.seek_to) method could be helpful for this. It allows positioning the JSON reader at the specified path, skipping all other values. This will likely be more efficient memory-wise than having to deserialize the complete JSON data as `Value` first before obtaining the relevant deeply nested portion.

You could then use Struson's `JsonReader` method `begin_array` to start the enclosing JSON array and then use within that `begin_array`, `end_array` and `next_number` to read the `(f64, f64)` values (assuming they look like `[1.2, 3.4]` in JSON).

```rust
// Assumes this is roughly the structure of your JSON data
let json = r#"
{
    "subtree": [
        [
            [1.2, 3.4],
            [-4.5, 6]
        ]
    ]
}     
"#;
// `std::io::Read` providing the JSON data; in this example the str bytes
let reader = json.as_bytes();

let mut xs: Vec<(f64, f64)> = Vec::new();

let mut json_reader = JsonStreamReader::new(reader);
json_reader.seek_to(&json_path!["subtree", 0])?;
json_reader.begin_array()?;

while json_reader.has_next()? {
    // Read the (f64, f64) values
    json_reader.begin_array()?;
    xs.push((
        json_reader.next_number()??,
        json_reader.next_number()??
    ));
    json_reader.end_array()?;
}

// Optionally consume the remainder of the JSON document
json_reader.skip_to_top_level()?;
json_reader.consume_trailing_whitespace()?;

println!("xs: {xs:?}");
```

Alternatively if you really wanted to use Serde-like functionality to deserialize the `Vec<(f64, f64)>`, you could use the [`serde` feature](https://docs.rs/struson/0.2.0/struson/serde/index.html) instead:

```rust
let json = r#"
{
    "subtree": [
        [
            [1.2, 3.4],
            [-4.5, 6]
        ]
    ]
}     
"#;
// `std::io::Read` providing the JSON data; in this example the str bytes
let reader = json.as_bytes();

let mut json_reader = JsonStreamReader::new(reader);
json_reader.seek_to(&json_path!["subtree", 0])?;

// Uses Serde's Deserialize implementation
let xs: Vec<(f64, f64)> = json_reader.deserialize_next()?;

// Optionally consume the remainder of the JSON document
json_reader.skip_to_top_level()?;
json_reader.consume_trailing_whitespace()?;

println!("xs: {xs:?}");
```

---

Disclaimer: I am the author of Struson, and currently it is still experimental (but feedback is highly appreciated!).